# Unable to locate package gcc-6 on Debian

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation, gcc

I am unable to install gcc-6 on Debian when I run `sudo apt-get install gcc-6`. It says `E: Unable to locate package gcc-6`.

The lowest version `gcc` will go via `apt-get` is 7. Is there a special repository I need to setup in order to get older `gcc` verisons? I tried to build gcc-6 from source but struggled, so if that is the only way to get a working copy of gcc-6, it would be much appreciated if you could walk me through the steps or show me a solid resource for doing this.

For reference, my system information is as follows:

```
user@debian:~$ uname -a
Linux debian 4.19.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.98-1 (2020-01-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The reason I am looking for an older `gcc` version is that I am trying to compile an older version of Linux (3.19) but I keep getting an error with newer `gcc` versions (7 & 8) stating:

```
include/linux/compiler-gcc.h:106:1: fatal error: linux/compiler-gcc7.h: No such file or directory
#include gcc_header(__GNUC__)
^~~~
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: If it’s saying ‘’compiler-gcc7.h: No such file or directory’’, I would question whether you have gcc-7 installed correctly.  Can you compile other things with it?

Comment: The error I believe is arising because kernel v3.19 doesn't support gcc compilers beyond v5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of 2020-02-08 gcc-6 is available as debian/strech package (oldstable).

https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=gcc-6&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

You may add oldstable to [`/etc/apt/sources.list`](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList?action=show&redirect=sources.list).

---

https://wiki.debian.org/DebianOldStable

> **oldstable** is a codename for the previous Debian stable repository, as long as security updates are provided. It is not just a name of the old stable version(s) of Debian.

Comment: So I added the two lines `deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/ oldstable main contrib non-free` and `deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/ oldstable main contrib non-free` to `/etc/apt/sources.list` but `gcc-6` is still not found.

Comment: Have you execute `apt-get update` **after** adding oldstable to `sources.list`?  it is necessary to make `apt-get install …` see new available packages.

Comment: That was the issue. Thank you!

Comment: @AnFi even after `apt-get update` it gives the same error on Ubuntu-20.04, I added the lines mentioned in peachykeen's comment.

Comment: Ubuntu includes gcc6 in `Bionic` release https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcc-6 => Try asking for more Ubuntu help at https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: `oldstable` is currently `buster`. Also, `archive.debian.org` seems dead. Add `stretch` directly if you need `gcc-6`: `deb https://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free` and 
`deb-src https://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free` in `/etc/apt/sources.list`